# How to do comparison of BigDecimal value in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I tried compareTo but sometimes it fails, sometimes it doesnot, can anyone provide an example for the same in kotlin

Comment: What do you mean "sometimes it fails"? The answer to "How do you do comparison of __ in Kotlin" is "use comparisons", so if that's not working for you then you'll have to be way more specific.

Comment: Please provide some code showing what you've tried (and explain how it doesn't do what you expect).